# How do I programmatically get the Keyboard Repeat settings in KDE?

Tags: c++, linux, api, redhat, kde-plasma

I have a custom Motif Widget and I'd like to tie its behavior to the Keyboard Repeat settings.
How do I programmatically get the current KDE Control Center `Keyboard Repeat` settings of `Delay` and `Rate`?  What API exists to query and set these values?

Also, how can I register to find out when the user changes these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XKB library functions `XkbGetAutoRepeatRate` and `XkbSetAutoRepeatRate` can be used to access the X server repeat delay and rate settings.  The functions are documented on their own man pages.  There is also `XAutoRepeatOn` and `XAutoRepeatOff` in the basic X library.

Note that the rate and delay settings are provided by the XKB extension and are not available in the raw X protocol, but nowadays you can probably assume that the XKB extension is always available.

You will need KDE toolkit functions if you want to save the settings for future sessions, since it is not possible at the raw X level.  Unfortunately I don't know anything about them.

Comment: Fortunately, saving is not necessary at the moment.  I'll look into these, thanks!